# MD5 with Full Charset, Make String Shorter, but how?

Tags: c#, md5, short, character-encoding

I know I can use MD5 easily in c#, the code I use is below:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
public static string MD5(string input)
{
    MD5CryptoServiceProvider x = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] bs = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
    bs = x.ComputeHash(bs);
    System.Text.StringBuilder s = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    foreach (byte b in bs)
    {
        s.Append(b.ToString("x2").ToLower());
    }
    return s.ToString();
}
```

Normally, MD5 string is 32 chars long with 0-9 and a-f.
I was wondering, if I use 0-9 A-Z a-z and _ . - etc, which will make around 64 chars set, and the MD5 string will be significant shorter. I will use the MD5 string to identify something and save in database. A shorter string can do the same thing and take less space, take less time to index.

So here, my question, is here anyone has a fast method to change 0-9a-f string to 0-9A-Za-z._ string

p.s. I have a basic idea is change MD5 string to a int(will be very big), then transfer to a string with any charset. I can imaging it will slow.

Any idea helps. Thanks.

**[EDIT]**

Thank you everyone, eventually I roll out one of my own,
I need a string, because I need it as part of URL as well.
For the reason I don't use Base64 because I want a fixed length string.

MD5 is 16 chars and length is 32, when I change it to 64 chars, length become 20.

here is the updates function I use.

```
public static string MD520(string input) 
{
    char[] chars = new char[] { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '_', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '-', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' };
    MD5CryptoServiceProvider x = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] bs = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
    bs = x.ComputeHash(bs);
    System.Text.StringBuilder s = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    byte m = 0;
    int c = 0;
    foreach (byte b in bs)
    {
        if (m == 2)
        {
            c = c * b;
            for (byte i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                int n = c % 64;
                s.Append(chars[n]);
                c = (c - n) / 64;
            }
            m = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            c = ((m > 0) ? c : 1) * b;
            m++;
        }
    }
    return s.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
    System.Text.StringBuilder s = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    foreach (byte b in bs)
    {
        s.Append(b.ToString("x2").ToLower());
    }
    return s.ToString();
```

You could use

```
    return Convert.ToBase64String(bs);
```

This will result in a shorter string but doesn't use the full charset.  You'd have to create your own custom encoding for that, though I wouldn't doubt someone out there already has.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save it in the least space possible, save the bytes; don't convert it to a string, as your code is doing. It *is* 32 bytes of data. Period. By displaying it as a string, you are balooning it 2 or 4 times, or more.

Don't try to roll some custom scheme... just don't baloon it in the first place.

(also, md5 is considered weak now, you know, right?)

Comment: I have to use a string, because it's part of URL. MD5 is weak, but I just use it check identical of tags, even collision, doesn't matter :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't really need it to be readable string, just use binary field. Otherwise, using Base64 would be most convenient.

Comment: This answer is likely going to cause the questioner to end up with an even *longer* string, because he will likely Base64 the string, not the bytes. It should be clarified, imo.